# Divide COUNT Column By COUNT(DISTINCT(Column To give avg order size SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok I have a list of the months orders so that bit is easy.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ITEMS,
```

For the next part easy to:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(PICKSET_NO))AS PICKSETS,
```

Its the next part I cant work out:

```
SUM(ITEMS/PICKSETS) AS AVGPICKSETSIZE
FROM dbo.orders
```

Thanks for your help on this.  Here is the code in one block.

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS ITEMS,
COUNT(DISTINCT(PICKSET_NO))AS PICKSETS,
SUM(ITEMS/PICKSETS)
FROM dbo.CollationOrders
GO
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. Write `COUNT(DISTINCT PICKSET_NO)` to make the code clearer.

Comment: Sorry jarih its something I picked up from my MySQL days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeat the expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ITEMS,
       COUNT(DISTINCT PICKSET_NO) AS PICKSETS,
       COUNT(*) / (1.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT PICKSET_NO))
FROM dbo.CollationOrders;
```

You can't re-use column aliases in the same `select`.

The 1.0 is to prevent integer division.

Comment: Aren't you missing a pair of parenthesis in the division expression?

Comment: Looking at the completed data I have I don't need the 1.0 part but I would love it not to round the total.
Not sure why I did not think of this a few hours ago!

Comment: @JustinGreenwood . . . As the OP, you are free to accept any answer you want.  But I'm curious why you unaccepted this answer.

Comment: Hi Gordon Your answer worked both the answers I was sent are correct. I had to remove the 1.0 from yours for some reason. Jay's answer get me that bit closer.

Comment: I have even posted my own answer now

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this:

```
SELECT ITEMS,
       PICKSETS,
       ITEMS / (1.0 * PICKSETS)
FROM (
       SELECT COUNT(*) AS ITEMS,
              COUNT(DISTINCT PICKSET_NO) AS PICKSETS     
       FROM TableName)t
```

Comment: Thanks Jay thats just what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS ITEMS,
    COUNT(DISTINCT om.PicksetNo) AS PICKSETS ,
    FORMAT(COUNT(*) / (1.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT om.PicksetNo)),'N2'),
   ca.YWK AS YWK
FROM CHDS_Common.dbo.OMOrder om
INNER JOIN CHDS_Management.dbo.Calendar ca ON om.EarliestPickDate = ca.DT
GROUP BY ca.YWK
```